# How can I do this query

Tags: mysql

how can i do this query. I need to show the student data and the parents information in one line. This is the query.

```
select da.nombre, da.apPaterno, da.apMaterno, f.nombre, f.aPaterno,
f.aMaterno, f.parentesco , fa.nombre, fa.aPaterno, fa.parentesco from 
datoaspirante as da
left join familiar as f on da.familiarid = f.datoaspirante
left join familiar as fa on da.familiarid = fa.datoaspirante
where fa.parentesco = 'Madre' and f.parentesco = 'Padre';
```

but this query only show the students that have a father and a mother and i need to show the student that only have a father or only have a mother or students that not have parents any idea?

This is the student table:

[image: This is the student table:]

This is the parent table:

[image: This is the parent table:]

Comment: Give sample data for both tables and your expected output based on that.

Answer (score 1):

You're filtering out all empty rows where either father and mother isnt set `where fa.parentesco = 'Madre' and f.parentesco = 'Padre';`

Moving conditions to the join, should get the behavior you want.

```
SELECT da.nombre, da.apPaterno, da.apMaterno, f.nombre, f.aPaterno,
f.aMaterno, f.parentesco, fa.nombre, fa.aPaterno, fa.parentesco
FROM 
datoaspirante AS da
LEFT JOIN familiar AS f ON da.familiarid = f.datoaspirante and f.parentesco = 'Padre'
LEFT JOIN familiar AS fa ON da.familiarid = fa.datoaspirante and fa.parentesco = 'Madre';
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have not mentioned sample data, I am only assuming this is what you want.

```
select d.*,f.*
,case 
    when f.datoaspirante is null 
    then 'No parents'
    else 'Single parent'
end as type
from 
datoaspirante d
left join 
(select datoaspirante from familiar
group by datoaspirante
having count(*)<2
) f
on d.familiarid = f.datoaspirante
```